# Case insensitive dictionary lookup in Python one-liner called from bash

Tags: python, bash

I'm not finding a solution to this, even on the other topics here relating to case insensitive dictionaries in Python.

I have a bash script, and I need to look up a value from a .json file, using a key extracted from another .json file. (These files are part of Chrome extensions.) The easiest way I've found to do this is by putting Python one-liners in the bash script. Here's what I've got right now:

```
extName=$(cat "$localePath" | python -c "import sys, json; sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin)['"$nameKey"']['message'])")
```

Here's the problem... Chrome doesn't seem to care about case in its json files, and in some extensions, the case of the key that I've previously extracted (from the extension's manifest.json) into $nameKey does not match the case of the key in $localePath (a path to a messages.json file in one of the extension's _locales folders).

Is there a way to do this in a Python one-liner, or am I going to have to find a different way to do this?

Comment: Can there be mixed case keys like `'KeY'` or is it either the content of `$nameKey` or `$nameKey` in all lower case?

Comment: Unrelated, but it is safer to pass `nameKey` as an argument rather than trying to interpolate it into the Python script. `python -c "...; write(load(stdin)[argv[1]]['message'])" "$nameKey" < "$localePath"`.

Comment: The nameKey value is taken straight from a Chrome extension, so it's unlikely that it would be a dangerous value, but point taken. However, that syntax doesn't seem to work. I get error messages that "name 'argv' is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant one-liner ever, but you can transform all your dict keys and values to lower-case entries and to consult it using a lower case key as well.

Python 2.x:

```
extName=$(cat "$localePath" | python -c "import sys, json; {key.lower(): value.lower() for key, value in sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin).iteitems()}['"$nameKey"'.lower()]['message'])")
```

Python 3.x:

```
extName=$(cat "$localePath" | python -c "import sys, json; {key.lower(): value.lower() for key, value in sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin).items()}['"$nameKey"'.lower()]['message'])")
```

Comment: That generates a syntax error, with a caret pointing at the closing '}':
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys, json; {key.lower(): value.lower() for key, value in sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin).iteitems()}['APP_NAME'.lower()]['message'])

Comment: I've corrected the syntax errors in the Python 2.x line, but I still get an error that I don't understand, as all the objects I'm calling lower() on should be strings, not dicts. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong, I assumed that you had a dict of strings which is not your case. Can you give an example of your dict content?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I fixed some of the issues in Aurora's suggested solution for Python 2.x, and ended up with this, which works:

```
extName=$(cat "$localePath" | python -c "import sys, json; sys.stdout.write(dict((key.lower(), value) for key, value in json.load(sys.stdin).iteritems())['""$nameKey""'.lower()]['message'])")
```